# Creating SQS Queues with lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm working on a collaborative document project (basically a clone of google docs), where client-programs post their actions to an API on amazon's API gateway, then receive messages of other client's actions via an SQS queue. The API calls trigger Node.js lambda functions that create a message, publish it to an SNS which then notifies each client's SQS.

My current hurdle is in dynamically creating/destroying SQS queues for these clients as they join/leave a document, however my googlefu is weak and I have failed to find anything that could help me. I'd like to keep the queue management server-side and ideally in lambda, but if that's impossible I will accept other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [AWS SDK for Javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sdk-for-node-js/) in your AWS Lambda function (it's already [pre-installed there](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)) and use it to manage any kind of AWS resources, e.g. the requested [creation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#createQueue-property) and [deletion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteQueue-property) of SQS queues.